# How do I protect variable using IIFE?

Tags: javascript

I have code that requires to run when the document is loaded but I need to protect my variable since some of it might conflict to other library.

Shortened Code.

```
function initialize() {
  console.log('running')
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

What I have tried

IIFE (failed)

```
(function initialize() {
  console.log('running')
})

window.onload = initialize;
```

IIFE running window.onload inside (Running)

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() { 
    console.log('running')
  }
})()
```

Is it the proper way of iife and onload? Thanks

Comment: But then what keeps your onload handler from conflicting with other libraries'?

Comment: From the snippet you provided I don't see how something could conflict. Are you talking about the window.onload might conflict with other libraries?

Comment: just run your code if error happens rename/recode ^^v

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill It won't affect if I use the last one I provide. Is it the proper way to do it?

Comment: If you're worried about conflicting with other libraries, you also need to think about how you're smashing whatever is currently in `window.onload`.

Comment: The second one is fine, your function is not available outside of that function, you are however overriding any previous window.oiad, you should use addEventListener. Is your question why didn't the first one work?

Comment: @josh it's in case huge the OP created a function / variable called $, jQuery, _, or one of those

Comment: @JuanMendes I can't use addEventListener since I am developing a site for all browser including IE6

Comment: @kevin then at least store any existing onload handler eand call it when yours gets called. IE 6, ar you kidding me?

Comment: If IE6 is a requirement for your work, then find a new job FAST.

Comment: @torazaburo It's hard to find a new job and It's fun to learn.

Comment: Learning about IE6 is a very strange definition of "fun". What are you going to study next, 7090 assembler?